# TriggeredSend email quese and caching

Tags: marketing-cloud, queue, cache

While calling TriggeredSend in a loop - does it create a queue and processes the email or does ExactTarget sends email right away?

We are sending email to list of people by calling TriggeredSend in a loop to send individual's  details to to ExactTarget BUT it seems user information on individual's gets mixed up.

Does anyone has any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Triggered Send calls are queued and processed in the order in which they were received.

You can view the queue in your SFMC account in the Email app under `Interactions > Triggered Emails`.

If your Triggered Send Definition is configured to write to a [templated Data Extension](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_data_extension_from_a_template/), then you can view the payload of the Triggered Send Request.

More info here: [Triggered Email Scenario Guide for Developers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/)